# Moving a canvas from left to right is not smooth and fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, mouseevent

I want to move one canvas on top of another. when top canvas moves the base canvas displays its x and y. The event initially starts at mouse down. so press mouse and start moving the canvas moves smoothly from right to left but not left to right.

http://jsfiddle.net/happyomi/23PL3/3/

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            position: absolute; 
            /* top: 0;
            left: 0;*/
        }
        #temp {
            background-color: pink;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="display: block;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="temp" style="position: relative">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var hgap = 0;
        var vgap = 0;
        var rows, cols;
        var annotation_x = 1;
        var row = 0; var col = 0;

        //ctx.font = "14px Arial";
        c.width = $(document).width();
        c.height = $(document).height();

        var t = document.getElementById("temp");
        tctx = t.getContext("2d");
        // tctx.lineWidth = 10;
        tctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        tctx.lineCap = 'round';
        tctx.strokStyle = 'red';

        var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        c.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
            mouse.x = evt.pageX;
            mouse.y = evt.pageY;

        }, false);
        c.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
            //    tctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            evt.preventDefault();
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            tctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            mouse.x = evt.pageX;
            mouse.y = evt.pageY;
            t.style.left = mouse.x + "px";
            t.style.top = mouse.y + "px";
            t.style.position = "absolute";
            str = "x=" + mouse.x + "  y=" + mouse.y;
            ctx.fillText(str, 10, 10);
            c.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false);

        var onPaint = function () {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            tctx.clearRect(0, 0, t.width, t.height);
            t.style.left = mouse.x + "px";
            t.style.top = mouse.y + "px";
            t.style.position = "absolute";
            str = "x=" + mouse.x + "  y=" + mouse.y;
            ctx.fillText(str, 10, 10);
        }
        c.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
            c.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres A good Starting point for ya :) it does what your looking for. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Keleko34/y3RKG/)

```
/* Main Canvas */
var main = document.getElementById('main');
main.width = window.innerWidth;
main.height = window.innerHeight;
var mainCtx = main.getContext('2d');
var mainFill = '#000';
mainCtx.fillStyle = mainFill;
mainCtx.rect(0,0,main.width,main.height);
mainCtx.fill();

 /* secondary canvas */
var cv = document.createElement('canvas');
cv.style.position = 'absolute';
cv.width = '200';
cv.height = '100';
cv.style.left = '0px';
cv.style.top = '0px';
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
var fillRect = '#ccc';
var fillText = '#000';
ctx.fillStyle = fillRect;
ctx.rect(0,0,cv.width,cv.height);
ctx.fill();

//draw this canvas to main canvas
mainCtx.drawImage(cv,parseInt(cv.style.left),parseInt(cv.style.top));

var isHolding = false;
var mDown = function(e)
{
    isHolding = true;
    main.addEventListener('mousemove',mMove);
}

var mMove = function(e)
{
    console.log('moving');
    if(isHolding)
    {
         var xPos = e.pageX;
         var yPos = e.pageY;
         cv.style.left = (xPos-(cv.width/2))+'px';
         cv.style.top = (yPos-(cv.height/2))+'px';
         cv.width = cv.width; //clears canvas
         ctx.fillStyle = fillRect;
         ctx.rect(0,0,cv.width,cv.height);
         ctx.fill();
         ctx.fillStyle = fillText;
         ctx.fillText('x: '+e.pageX,10,10);
         ctx.fillText('y: '+e.pageY,50,10);

        //draw temp canvas to main canvas
        this.width = this.width;
        mainCtx.fillStyle = mainFill;
        mainCtx.rect(0,0,main.width,main.height);
        mainCtx.fill();
        mainCtx.drawImage(cv,parseInt(cv.style.left),parseInt(cv.style.top));
    }
}

var mUp = function(e)
{
    isHolding = false;
    main.removeEventListener('mousemove',mMove);
}

main.addEventListener('mousedown',mDown);
main.addEventListener('mouseup',mUp);
```

also it gets rid of the move event when not being used which will help have less event dispatches in memory and help with performance.

Comment: thanks for spending your time. but the requirement is to move one canvas on top of another.and main canvas is full width and height where as top canvas can be any size.

Comment: so you want the smaller canvas to be drawn to the larger canvas?

Comment: exactly what i have done, smaller canvas will be moving as well. and not effecting the contents on larger canvas when moved. the only issue i have is to get smooth mouse movements

Comment: I have update the jsFiddle to dynamicly draw a created canvas onto the main one as specified, it is much better to dynamicly create the temp canvas in code using document.createElement('canvas') if it is just going to be drawn to the main anyways. I will also update answer. http://jsfiddle.net/Keleko34/y3RKG/

Comment: @ Keleko. the issue is still there. mouse movement is not smooth. when u move mouse towards left.. its fine but once it is moved to left if  you try moving to right side it does not move rather jumps on destination and destination x,y is not correct.

Comment: u have changed the x and y to middle of canvas and it is required to be on top left. dont worry I will try to fix it. Thanks for spending so much time